# Connect pairs of data points in a XY scatter chart

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to format the chart below, so that the area between the pairs of points is shaded. I know this is pretty easy to do with points that are not at the same x-value, but that is not the case.

Also, I have a table where it gets the data from, and it would be nice if it could auto-update the shading, without me having to make the shading of certain points invisible every time.

[image]

Comment: Does an area chart do what you want?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the lines of the area chart jump up to the points above.

Comment: How would that look? Can you manually draw on the chart and post the expected result? For example the 9/18 has two pairs. I can't picture what you want to see.

Comment: Not the best paint job, but something [like this.](http://i.imgur.com/jNXmEEV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Error Bars to connect the data points with lines.

First, add a formula that calculates the time difference. Then add vertical error bars to the upper series: Select the upper series and on the Chart Tools > Layout ribbon select the Error Bars drop-down and click "More Error Bars Options".

Set the Vertical error bars to have "minus" direction, no cap and a custom error amount. Select the range with the calculated time difference as the "Negative Error Value".

Format line color and line style with your desired color and thickness and close the dialog.

There will be spidery horizontal error bars in the chart. Select and delete them.

Format the data markers for both series to "None".

[image]